# Angular - has been blocked by CORS Policy - header - Request header field authentication is not allowed

Tags: angular, request, header, cors

Yes I looked many of the similar questions about CORS and the header.
I tried many of them but still I get this error in Google Chrome.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://service.domain.com/clientlist' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:
Request header field authentication is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

My code :

```
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          authentication: `Basic ${myCredentials}`,
          'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, authentication, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers',
        }
      });
```

I even tried in it combination with these following options :

```
'access-control-allow-credentials': true,
'access-control-allow-origin': 'http://localhost:4200',
```

${myCredentials} => is filled in correctly, because when I run :

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C://Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security
```

it runs good, and also the call after to a webservice works perfectly !
Because I use :

```
export class BasicAuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
...
}
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Looks like the problem is serverside (it really always is with CORS). It seems the options response is returning auth information.

Comment: Try `Authorization` as the request-header name, rather than `authentication`. And remove Access-Control-Allow-Headers from the setHeaders values in your frontend code; Access-Control-Allow-Headers is a response header, not a request header.

Comment: Thank you both... The problem is the programmer used "authentication" instead of "Authorization" ( to call his webservice I mean )...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution for my case, is to use the standard field "Authorization" AND removing the line "Access-Control-Allow-Headers".
There are some restrictions on the server side, but our IT can't change it.

Many thanks to MikeOne AND sideshowbarker !!!!

The final code :

```
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: `Basic ${myCredentials}`,
        }
      });
```

Have a nice day !